# How do I know when a user in Facebook posts something to his timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I know when a user in Facebook posts something through my Facebook app ?

I don't wanna use the normal polling method it'll be very server-exhaustive if my app grows even to 2000 Users.

My app needs to fetch posts of the user and search for special Tags in it e.g #Send_To_App in order to get these posts and replicate it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I found that I should Use Subscribe to Live updates (it's somehow a hidden option in the App-Settings)

Answer (score 1):

well surely if they're posting something through your app you should now when they are posting it! If you're using javascript for this then you can use event.subscribe

```
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
```

and if you're using php or something similar to hit the graph api, then it will most likely return you an ID for the object that was created and you can store that and then use an FQL query to retreive those

Comment: They're not posting through my app, I need my app which have a permission to read their stream/feed posts to know every time they post something not through my app, I can do this through polling but it'll be very server-exhaustive when my app reaches higher number of users

Comment: ah ok, so in your app you want to be notified when a user posts on Facebook. It's just your initial question said "How do I know when a user in Facebook posts something through my Facebook app ?" I assumed you meant they were posting something via your app. You can try using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ though it only supports certain connections,but feed is one of them